# running in production mode on local machine accesses heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, heroku, puma

I am trying to run in production mode on my local machine using `puma`. If I type

```
rails server -e production
```

the server starts up with a message

```
Puma 2.16.0 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

When I type into the browser (chrome or safari),

```
http://localhost:3000
```

instead of accessing the local server, it goes to the real production site on heroku. I tried clearing the browser cache and it still goes to Heroku. How do I fix this?

Note that if I stop the server, and run in development mode, the browser still goes to Heroku, but if I clear the browser cache, it goes to the local server again.

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 3000`

Comment: using ```RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 3000``` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had the following code in an initializer

```
MyApp::Application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 /.*/, 'http://www.myapp.com$&', if: proc {|rack_env|
    rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.myapp.com'
  }
end if Rails.env == 'production'
```

which was for a redirect for the naked domain. If I turned this off for my local machine, `rails s -e production` correctly directs to local host.